# Copy the calls of the button using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, button, click

So a project has been passed to me and there is a button on a Twitter bootstrap sidebar doing a search dynamically. I cannot figure out which calls the button is making, and I need to replicate its functionality with another button. (We want two buttons doing the same thing) is there a way to use jquery (find maybe?) to do this? I was trying something like this:

```
$side-bar.find('#newSearchButton').on('click', function(){
    $side-bar.find('#oldSearchButton')._data.events.click[0].handler;
});
```

I know this is wrong, but I don't know what to do to make it work. I just want to be able to make the new search button perform the same search as the old search button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't you use a function that when new button is clicked, clicks old button, hence doing the magic behind the old button.

```
$('#newSearchButton').click(function(){
    $('#oldSearchButton').click();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set same callback to a list of objects. In your case, you can do:

```
$side-bar.find('.MyButton').on('click', function(){
    // do something
});
```

Note that you have to include class="MyButton" to your buttons tags for this to work.